# error with property in objective-c in iOS

Tags: ios, class, properties, interface, definition

I have started new iOS project and have added only one property in ViewControler header file. but it gives me error:

> expected specifier-qualifier-list before 'property'

here is the code:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface QuoteGenViewController : UIViewController {

    @property (retain) NSArray *myQuotes;
}

@end
```

Comment: @ property outside interface block before @end

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here the general structure of a class interface

```
@interface Class : Superclass
{
    // Instance variable declarations.
    // Theirs definition could be omitted since you can declare them
    // in the implementation block or synthesize them using declared properties.
}
// Method and property declarations.
@end
```

Since a property provides a simple way to declare and implement an object’s accessor methods (getter/setter), you need to put them in the *Method and property declarations* section.

I really suggest to read [ocDefiningClasses](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/cocoa/conceptual/objectivec/Chapters/ocDefiningClasses.html) doc for this.

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 2):

Your code should look like this:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface QuoteGenViewController : UIViewController {

}

@property (retain) NSArray *myQuotes;

@end
```